# apt-get could not open lock file

Tags: installation, apt, sudo, root

I am trying to get an nfs client running on a Sheeva-plug running debian 2.6.22. The host is Ubuntu 12.04 and claims (from showmount -e) to be exporting the desired directory. There is no showmount binary in the sheeva-plug, so I'm trying to install it from the nfs-common package:

```
 # apt-get install nfs-common
```

The response ends with

```
 E: could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (no such file or directory)
 E: Unable to lock the download directory.
```

I am root while doing this. Similar errors arise when trying to install other packages.

How do I correct these errors so apt-get will do its work?

Answer (score 6):

According to the error message the file `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock` doesn't exist anymore on your computer. You can just simply create it:

```
sudo touch /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

However maybe there is also another directory missing. Please have a look if `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial exists`. If not create it:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```

Now your installation should work as expected.