# My machine is returning this constantly, WHY?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

```
$ apt-get install gcc 
E: Type 'es' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: Hello. when asking a question it is a good idea to have searched the site first to see if the question was already asked. For example the https://askubuntu.com/questions/228454/apt-get-could-not-open-lock-file question has been asked many many times and that is an example.

Comment: You have 2 problems here. 1. APT needs `sudo` privileges. 2. sources.list is malformed.